# convert a list into a list of tuples with None included

Tags: python

I want to convert a list like this:
L = ['ad', 'bc', 'gh', 'kj', 'ws', 'er', 'th']

into [('ad', 'bc', 'gh', 'kj', 'ws'), ('er', 'th', None, None, None)] using python 3

The tuples will contain the equal amount of elements even if the list doesn't provide enough elements. So if i have 6 elements, i will get two tuples, one full of 5 elements and the other will have only one element and 4 Nones. But if i have only 5 elements i should get a list of one tuple containing 5 elements.

i tried zip but it doesn't give me the desired result

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Do you always need 2 tuples? Is the first one only containing 5 elements? The question is not really clear

Comment: no, not just two tuples, i want it to keep going for as many elements the list will contain. So if i have 100 elements, each tuple should contain 5 elements only, but if the elements amount cannot be divided to give 5 for each, then i want it to be covered up by None values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`grouper`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.grouper) from the [`more_itertools`](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/) package for this:

```
from more_itertools import grouper

l = ['ad', 'bc', 'gh', 'kj', 'ws', 'er', 'th']
result = list(grouper(l, 5, incomplete="fill", fillvalue=None))
print(result)
```

gives

```
[('ad', 'bc', 'gh', 'kj', 'ws'), ('er', 'th', None, None, None)]
```

Alternatively, as Tomerikoo [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73185157/convert-a-list-into-a-list-of-tuples-with-none-included/73185239?noredirect=1#comment129260688_73185239), you can construct the `grouper` function using [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) in the standard library:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, *, incomplete='fill', fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into non-overlapping fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, fillvalue='x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, incomplete='strict') --> ABC DEF ValueError
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, incomplete='ignore') --> ABC DEF
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    if incomplete == 'fill':
        return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
    if incomplete == 'strict':
        return zip(*args, strict=True)
    if incomplete == 'ignore':
        return zip(*args)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Expected fill, strict, or ignore')
```

Comment: There is also the [`grouper` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) from the built-in `itertools` which is just a two lines function

Comment: @Tomerikoo thanks, I've put that in the answer. To be pedantic, it is a 9-line function, not two, although you could compress it to 5 :P

Answer (score 0):

Python code:

```
def getTuples(size):
    intSize = size // 5
    if size / 5 > intSize:
        return (intSize + 1) * 5
    else:
        return intSize * 5
def convert(l):
    new = []
    t = ()
    tValue = 0

    for i in range(0, getTuples(len(l))):
        tValue += 1
        try:
            val = l[i]
        except IndexError:
            val = None
        if tValue == 5:
            new.append(t)
            t = ()
        else:
            t = t + (val,)
     new.append(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L = ['ad', 'bc', 'gh', 'kj', 'ws', 'er', 'th']

L3 = list()
idx = 0

while idx < len(L):

    L2 = list()
    for idx2 in range(5):
         L2.append(L[idx])
         idx = idx +1
         if idx >= len(L):
             break
    while idx2 < 4:
        L2.append(None)
        idx2 = idx2 + 1
    L3.append(tuple(L2))
print(L3)
```